# Stuck with Safari 6 beta

Tags: safari

I installed the Safari 6 beta a few weeks ago. Now that Safari 6 has been released for Lion, I can't seem to find anywhere to get it.

- The Safari [download page](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/) redirects to the [main Safari page](http://www.apple.com/safari/) with no download link.
- Apple's developer site, Apple's downloads and even the download for Safari 5.1.5 all link to the Safari download page (which as I mentioned doesn't have a download link).
- It is not listed in Software Update.

Here's my Software Update history showing that it hasn't been installed without me noticing:
[image: Software Update history]

Here's the Safari build I currently have:
[image: About Safari: Version 6.0 (7536.16)]

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're obviously a dev, so have you tried checking the Dev Center for the latest build?

Comment: For betas etc I would try deleting it and then see what Software Update then shows

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, as you can see the second bullet point states that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had expected the download to be on the Safari web site or the Safari Developer Center, neither of which has a link to the download.

I did manage to find it using de_an777's link. That link took me to a "your session is expired" message as he described but after logging in I was at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action.

Unchecking all of the options on the left except Safari gave me options to download the uninstaller. I'm now back on 5.1.7 and Software Update is downloading the release of Safari 6 right now.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same issue.

I have the developer preview of Safari 6 (Beta) installed on Lion and now that ML is out, I can no longer get the uninstaller from Apple's Developer Connection Website.  Like you said, all the links are stale and point me in the direction of the Safari Website with no download links.

All direct links to the Safari 6 Beta Uninstaller, like this one:

[Uninstaller](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Safari/safari_6_developer_preview_for_lion/safari_6_developer_preview_for_lion_uninstaller.dmg)

Do not work and say that your session has expired.

Unfortunately, at the moment, I have not been able to find a copy of that uninstaller or any older version of Safari to reinstall.  Usually though, the beta version is just superseded by newer versions that will be coming out eventually or they will release an update for beta users, or reissue links for the uninstaller.  Unless you can find the uninstaller somewhere, I would suggest doing nothing. Do not uninstall safari yourself or delete things, this might cause issues that could just as easily be fixed with patience. It suck to mess things up and make things worse when technically the Safari 6 Beta works just like Safari 6 for Lion.

I know it isn't the solution you were looking for, but everything will work itself out, either with Apple fixing things, or an update that just installs the newer version for you.

I hope that it helps.

Comment: I'm glad to know I'm not the only one at least.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 6 seems to be available from Software Update today (31 July 2012) for me (I had Safari 6 Preview 3 installed).

Uninstallers for previews 1 and 2 could be found on the Apple Developer site, but the uninstaller for preview 3 was no longer available there. I tried the uninstaller for preview 2, but that did not remove the preview 3 installation.