# Both Safari and Webkit crash on startup

Tags: macos, safari

I'm trying to debug [a Webkit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17178309/306084), and I seem to have botched my Safari installation: whenever I try to launch any version of Safari or Webkit, it crashes immediately with an error like this:

> Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/Safari.framework/Safari
>     Reason: image not found

I wasn't able to reproduce my bug in my installed Safari (6.0.5 on Mountain Lion (10.8.4)) but I was on the [Webkit nightly](http://nightly.webkit.org/) I downloaded and installed (r151773).

I was trying to pinpoint the Webkit revision where this became a problem, so I downloaded several more older nightlies, but when I tried launching any of those, they failed to launch with the error above. When I went back to the newer nightly, then to my original Safari, those were all showing the error as well.

I can't find an installer to reinstall Safari 6.0.5. In [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57755/4827) I found a route to download and install a developer build of Safari 6.1, but that also fails to launch with the same error.

How can I restore my Safari? And, once I get Safari back, is there a way to try several nightlies of Webkit so I can narrow down the scope of the change which created my problem?

Comment: It looks like your Safari is looking for a file in a wrong directory? Could you verify the location of the Webkit ?

Comment: `dhcp168:~ pmorse$ ls -l /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2`
ls: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2: No such file or directory

Comment: so where is the webkit ?

Comment: ...and yet: `dhcp168:~ pmorse$ ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit`

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  4510928 Jun 11 10:26 /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit

Comment: so u have older version of webkit installed, but not the webkit2 ? I found only way to get Safari 605 is true bundle :( http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [doing an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763). It should replace preinstalled frameworks and applications with the initial versions but keep user files and settings in place. I have done it twice so far and it solved multiple issues both times, so I have started to recommend it as a troubleshooting step here, even though no-one ever does it.

Another way to restore the directories for Safari or frameworks might be to copy them from a VM.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see how it works.

Comment: It worked, but took quite a while (~75 minutes) which seems like quite a process for (ultimately) reinstalling one app.

Comment: Pacifist does this nicely, in whatever parts of system and apps you want. http://www.charlessoft.com